# Make WAR executable like JAR to provide command line interface out of the application (JBoss)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, command-line, command-line-interface, war

I have a servlet which have some logic and is used via browser like every servlet. Now I am looking for method to do the same thing what servlet does, but it should work like CLI. CLI sends requests to logic deployed on JBoss (classes in war file) and print responses on terminal (command line). It should trigger the same logic and all things should be placed in this one war file.

So let's say I will write java code which provides this funcionality. It should be compiled to jar and placed in war, then this jar should be launched from war. It doesn't have to be a servlet. Only requirement is taht everything should be in this one war file. CLI should be called via one line, something like java -cp jarfileinwar com.blah.Main.

Logic should work on JBoss JVM where everything is deployed, it should work like servlet, but method of call should be CLI.

Greets

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. You want to provide a command line interface (CLI) for your deployed servlet based application to control your web application via command line? Right so far? What have you tried so far? Is your question about the communication protocol? The command line tool? What are your impediments?

Comment: The purpose is to have access to all deployed apps, make objects from classes wchich are in those apllications, run methods etc. I think you understand correctly. Hm, the best thing would be to use some JEE component which runs on JBoss and provides command line actions. Servlet is something like this, but interactions with user are made via browser, something like servlet, but via CLI would be great. So my first thought is to use servlet, but use other way of sending requests and get responses. I've found only that to make cli request I can use wget, but it is not a good solution.

Comment: I'll encourage you to make your question clearer by editing it. :) Some hints: it seems to me that you're not sure if to use servlets. Maybe there are other technologies, so your question could be more general?

Comment: Some more hints: it depends on your technologies too. Are you using EJBs? Are you using REST? What data are we talking about (text/binary)? Should your command line client cover all of your web client or only a small part?

Comment: Hm, important thing is that I have to place everything in this war file. So if it is not a servlet, but some java code it still have to be placed in war file. Then question is how to run jar file from inside of war file. Everything runs on JBoss, I'd rather like not to use EJBs. :p I don't know anything about REST, what opportunities does it provide? Requests and reponses are plain text. About last question I think I don't understand it fully. CLI should give opportunity to operate on all interfaces from all deployed applications.

Comment: One option could be to add a main class field to your .war manifest so that it's executable like a executable .jar. I've never done this before and don't know it this is working. But if I were in your situation, I would try this. ;) Another approach would be to package a runnable .jar in your .war file as a resource and make it downloadable through your web interface. You then have to ship a shell file that will download and execute the .jar ([Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+CLI) does it this way).

Comment: Executing code on your backend depends highly on the workflow and data. You could provide SOAP (or another [RMI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_remote_method_invocation)) or REST interfaces to your businesslogic and call it through appropriate client from your CLI. SOAP is complex and harder to maintain. REST is simpler, more straight forward, but not always the right choice for every problem. Were SOAP is a kind of remote method invocation, REST is "resource centric" and [CRUD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CRUD)

Comment: My question _"Should your command line client cover all of your web client or only a small part?"_ was not clear to you. I think, It was not clear enough. Consider this: it makes a huge difference if we're talking about 20 methods on 10 classes or 1 switch on three classes. If you're processing (storing/retrieving/updating) data, running business logic or switching log levels (e.g. in Log4J).

Comment: So I've added entry in MANIFEST.MF Main-Class: org.this.is.my.main.Class. Then I've tried to run it like this: java -jar App.war. And I got ClassNotfoundDefError. But surely I did something wrong. I have jar with main function and other jars which are also needed. Now they are in WEB-INF/lib. If I want to run this war as a jar where should I put this jar files?

Comment: Your last edit made the question clearer (_"Logic should work on JBoss JVM where everything is deployed"_). Forget my specluations about remote access. With `NoClassDefFound` (I assume you meant that) it is crucial which class was not found. Most likely an library your application is using.

Comment: As stated in [this answer about NoClassDefFound on executable .jars](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8276736/noclassdeffound-error-for-a-jar-created-using-ant-build#answer-8384941) it is not possible to have .jars packaged within .jar (or .war in your case). That matches my knowing. You could either try add the libraries unpackaged winthin your .war (not the best solution) or build a bootstrap code that will unpack the an startup class and the library .jars into a temporary directory executing the startup class from there.

Answer (score 0):

An executable jar file has a different structure from what a war file has, so I don't think that you're going to be successful in trying to create an executable war file.

You can, however, repackage your required classes and the classes from your jar dependencies into one big "uber jar", and then make that executable by means of the propert manifest entries.

Doing this is not straightforward by hand, so I'd suggest using a build tool to accomplish this. Maven has two plugins - the Shade plugin and the newer (I think) Maven Assembly plugin that can do this quite easily.

A benefit of using Maven is that you could have two different targets - one to build the war file, and one to build the executable jar file, from the same project.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't stop thinking about it. As I've commented the original post, I thought it is possible to make WAR files executable by imitating an executable JAR within a WAR.

On top of a Maven 3 web project arche type (as foundation) I've created a little proof of concept project that actually implements this.

Take a look:

https://github.com/is-already-taken/executable-war-example

It uses a custom classloader ([this article about classloaders from javablogging.com helped me dong this](http://www.javablogging.com/java-classloader-2-write-your-own-classloader/)), a "bootstrap" class that loads the first portion of business logic using our custom class loader and a custom Manifest. The classloader is used to "intercept" the class loading to search classes at the location where classes usually are located in a WAR file and to extract classes from libraries packaged within WAR files using streamed unzip code.

Maybe there's still such a out-of-box solution or something that comes with a Maven plugin, but I didn't found it. Further, this small proof of concept helped me leanring class cloader stuff aswell. ;)

I'm looking forward to comments on my solution and my approach in general.